# Problems with ajax in WordPress plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Iam trying to make a plugin folowing an online corse on WP plugins.

Iam having grave difficulties with the ajax part of the plugin (its an email list builder).

This is my .js jQuery code that is supposed to run some php code on the localhost and show the success/error message in an alert window:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){     

    var wpajax_url = document.location.protocol + '//' + document.location.host + 'wordpress_plugin_course/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=plb_save_subscribtion';

    $('form.plb-form').bind('submit', function(){

        $form = $(this);  
        var form_data = $form.serialize();

        $.ajax({
            'method':'post',
            'url':wpajax_url,
            'data':form_data,
            'dataType':'json',
            'cache':false,
            'success':function( data, textStatus ){
                if( data.status == 1 ){
                    $form[0].reset();       
                    alert(data.message);
                } else{
                    var msg = data.message +'\r'+ data.error + '\r';
                    $.each(data.errors,function(key,value){     
                        msg += '\r';
                        msg += '- ' + value;
                    });
                    alert( msg );                   
                }
            },
            'error':function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

            }

        });

        return false;           
    });

});
```

The php part (Yes, subscribtion with a B in it is intentional because I had problems with that gramatically and I decided it would be easier to just stick to B in all cases).

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_plb_save_subscribtion', 'plb_save_subscribtion');                    
add_action('wp_ajax_plb_save_subscribtion', 'plb_save_subscribtion');               
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'plb_public_scripts');     

function plb_public_scripts(){                                                              
    wp_register_script('profi-list-builder-js-public', plugins_url('/js/public/profi-list-builder.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'),'1.0',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('profi-list-builder-js-public');
}
```

Iam not showing the plb_save_subscribtion function because its hundreds of lines of code altogether and the code is working fine: it is saving  new subscriptions to a subscription post in the admin area and afterwards returning successs/error message in .json format to the client.

What I need jQuery to do now is do this posting via ajax and put that same plb_save_subscribtion response client gets into the alert window.

I've spent literaly all day googling, trying to solve this issue but to no avail. Iam out of ideas, so Iam posting it here. Is there something wrong with this code? If not, where should I be looking for the problem (because the code is copy/pasted and SHOULD work fine, but it doesn't)? If I put a simple alert message inside at the top of the function, alert message shows up like it's supposed to. But when I press submit on the form, page reloads and I get back message in .json, no alert window, no ajax. Somebody?

Comment: It's not because you copy/paste that the code will run. How are you enqueuing the jQuery file and does a wp_ajax_youraction runs to make it work for the admin url ? If you get the json error you are under th error close.

Comment: I think **action=plb_save_subscribtion** should be **action=plb_save_subscription** (but maybe the spelling error is consistent with the action). Actually an AJAX request problem without the server part is not really describing.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your plugins file

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_test_enqueue_scripts' );

function ajax_test_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom', plugins_url( '/custom.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'custom', 'postCustom', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ))
    );

}


function plb_save_subscribtion(){

    print_r($_POST['form_data']);

}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_plb_save_subscribtion', 'plb_save_subscribtion');                    
add_action('wp_ajax_plb_save_subscribtion', 'plb_save_subscribtion');
```

Add the following in your js file(here custom.js)

```
jQuery('form').bind('submit', function(){



        var form_data = jQuery(this).serialize();


      jQuery.ajax({
        url : postCustom.ajax_url,
        type : 'post',
        data : {
            action : 'plb_save_subscribtion',
            form_data : form_data
        },
        success : function( response ) {               
            alert(response);
        }
    });         
});
```

Try this way. You can see the form data in alert window.